# ServiceStack AutoQuery MaxLimit

Tags: servicestack

Is there a way to customize the ServiceStack AutoQuery MaxLimit setting per DTO? I have a use case where I'd prefer a smaller MaxLimit for one DTO compared to another, but I've only been able to set the MaxLimit once:

```
var aqf = new AutoQueryFeature
{
     MaxLimit = 100
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only 1 `MaxLimit` configuration option but you can customize it on a per-request basis by providing a [Custom Service implementation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Auto-Query#custom-autoquery-implementations), e.g:

```
public class MyQueryServices : Service
{
    public IAutoQuery AutoQuery { get; set; }

    //Override with custom implementation
    public object Any(FindMovies request)
    {
        var q = AutoQuery.CreateQuery(request, Request.GetRequestParams());
        q.Limit(request.Skip, newTake); //override with custom limit
        return AutoQuery.Execute(request, q);
    }
}
```